# OSPF Theory Question | Topology Changes | LSU Flooding

Tags: ospf, security

Could you create a script on an ospf router that enable/disables interfaces randomly, and faster than time neighbor routers update their LSDBs, making a network that's constantly flooded with LSU messages?

Comment: If someone can "create a script on an OSPF router" for anything, you definitely have a security problem... OSPF is an IGP and requires a high level of trust.

Comment: @Zac67 I don’t think that’s what they were asking. I think they were just asking if there was a way to do it in general, like using TCL scripting on a Cisco router to mess with interfaces.

Comment: @JesseP. That is what I was asking. Have you ever seen it done before? Or is there a limit to how many LSUs a router can send per unit of time?

Comment: @Ged See the answer below for this

Comment: @JesseP. I would upvote your answer if I could! You mentioned rate-limits can be turned off or at least made negligible. Can this be done to a single device to generate that effect on all neighbors, or would it need to be done to all participants?

Comment: @Ged Each participant.

Comment: @JesseP.  Do you think these rate-limits are the only form of protection against this kind of flood?

Comment: @Ged That, I can’t answer. It would depend on brand, model, settings, firmware versions that may have different protections/patches than another version, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you/someone could create a script that shuts down and re-enables interfaces randomly very easily.

Depending on the device and model, there are rate-limits on LSU transmission, to protect against flooding.  [Here](https://techhub.hpe.com/eginfolib/networking/docs/switches/5950/5200-4015_l3-ip-rtng_cr/content/499753967.htm) is one document for HPE devices, just as an example, showing that the default is 50 LSUs within 30ms.

There are also rate-limits on command entry, so that would need to be accounted for as well.

This is of course highly advised against, for what should be very obvious reasons.